# Facebook App Invites for Android

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to test App Invites for Android (facebook sdk) but I never see this dialog.

```
if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) 
{
   AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                              .setApplinkUrl(appLinkUrl)
                              .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
                              .build();
   AppInviteDialog.show(this, content);
}
```

How can I solve ? My app is not a game but reading facebook's documentation, I can use App Invites too.

Comment: Have you called    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
on your onCreate method?

Comment: Yes, I solved just now. There was a problem with my token so I solved unistalling Facebook and re-installing it.